# How to solve the differential equation $y' = \frac{2xy}{x^2-y^2}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following differential equation:
$$y' = \frac{2xy}{x^2-y^2}$$

Someone please help me start this problem. This does not look like a regular first-order differential equation in the form  $y' + 2xy = x$. Thank you.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1213288/solving-the-differential-equation-x2-y2y-2xy-0?rq=1

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2241172/how-to-solve-the-differential-equation-y-fracxyx-y/2241178?noredirect=1#comment4611633_2241178 make sure you learn the techniques of previous questions!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You can write $y' = \dfrac{\frac{2y}{x}}{1 - \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2}$ and use $u = \frac{y}{x}$.

Comment: How do we know to break the function like that?

Comment: @socrates It is what is called a "homogeneous differential equation"  So, it is always something to look out for.